# Connecting to Amazon RDS Mysql from a server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm struggling to connect to my Mysql instance on Amazon RDS from a web server. I get this error:

`Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.
 Debugging errno: 2005
 Debugging error: Unknown MySQL server host 'my-database-address.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (20)`

Using this connection function:

`$connect = mysqli_connect("my-database-address.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "username", "password","database");`

I've setup my Instance to use a Security Group with the following settings:

```
RULE     | TYPE         | PROTOCOL  |  PORT RANGE  |  SOURCE
Inbound  | MYSQL/Aurora | TCP       |  3306        |  Anywhere
Outbound | MYSQL/Aurora | TCP       |  3306        |  Anywhere
```

Am I missing some rules in my security group? Should I specify the server IP address instead of chosing "Anywhere". Or is my function wrong?

Comment: check if you can ping or telnet to your DB server using the hostname .

Comment: Ah, same error when pinging from Terminal: cannot resolve ... : Unknown host when using the :3306 as a part of the address. Without :3306 I get Recuest timeout for icmp_sec

Comment: Is your mysql and webserver both are in the same region.

Comment: I'm using a corporate webserver, so I don't know which region webserver is located.

Comment: don't you have access to amazon management console , your db server is located in eu-west-1 region btw. if you have access to management console then you can check the public DNS of your web-server.

Comment: try `telnet  <db-hostname> 3306`

Comment: if the webserver is inside your VPC, it is important the webserver is using the same subnet group as configure by RDS db_subnet_group. If the webserver  subnet is not specify by the assigned RDS db_subnet_group, add it.  More details (mask out those sensitive info) will help solving the issue ASAP.

Comment: `telnet <db-hostname> 3306` works.  Connected to ec2..etc.
I have access to Amazon console. The webserver is not an Amazon server.

Comment: You cannot ping a databse! instead use telnet server_ip 3306, or alternatively, please install mysql client and connect to your db using your password.

Comment: @FilipBlaauw . can you provide your `db-user` remote connection permission.

Comment: Check if user is allowed for remote connection , 
      ```   Allow a user to connect from anywhere
         GRANT ALL ON *.* to <user-name>@'<ip>' IDENTIFIED BY '<passwd>';
         sample :- GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'; // grant root user to connect from everywhere(%) , which has root passwd.``` for granting a user remote connection permission.

Comment: Did you enable the "publicly accessible" flag on the RDS instance?

Comment: @Sam: I suspect pinging the server was meant. That said, although it isn't an ICMP ping, there [was a specific MySQL ping command](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) before the `mysql` extension was removed.